# Lightning standard components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

Is there any way in Winter 15 to get access to standard lightning components?  If not thru drag and drop, is there a listing of such components by name and parameters, so that they can be included in a lightning app?

Comment: hamayoun - do you have a list of specific components you were looking for that you can share? I'm owning the effort to figure out what components we've built internally that we can expose to customers and partners and it would be great to understand some of the ones you wish you had but don't yet have access to!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

/auradocs/reference.app in your org will show you the complete set of components, attributes, events, and interfaces your org has access to. This set will be greatly expanded in the next major release. I am working on getting a doc put together to let you at least see what is coming out shortly to help you plan etc.