# showHeader for Lightning Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I need to show the following standard header in my Lightning Component. Is it possible?
[image]

Comment: Not sure about that component in particular, but there was a question earlier about accessing [Lightning standard components](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56749/lightning-standard-components)

Comment: Yes it's possible.. You need to use **Global Header** and **Global Navigation** components. Refer this [link](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/global-navigation/)

Comment: @RohitMourya Its Lightning Design System. I want to use in component. Is there any standard way?

Comment: @snehakem No, You'll need customization